# Android real escape string in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

How can i use php real_escape_string in android sqlite?

when i add the following to my table row's value "asd'" then i getting a crash because of "'" char. How can I escape illegal characters in android sqlite?

Thanks

edit: in android, not php

Comment: Is this question tagged properly?  Are you using PHP or Android development?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think an equivalent function is `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(stringToEscape)`. (Javadoc: SQL_escape a string).

If you are using the SQLiteDatabase `insert` method taking a `ContentValues` as a parameter, these *may* be automatically escaped for you, but I'm not 100% (and I haven't been able to check).